# simple read operating not reading any thing from char device linux

Tags: c, linux

I have a simple code that suppose to read length sized and fetch data from character device in Linux C.

This is my code and errno is set to 9. I made sure the file exists and it does. And able to read it with `cat /dev/mychardev-0` but why bad file descriptor error at time of read. I am getting this line passed `int fd=open("/dev/mychardev-0",O_RDONLY); if(fd<0)`

```
#include <fcntl.h> 
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
int main()
{

    int fd=open("/dev/mychardev-0",O_RDONLY);
    if(fd<0)
    {   
        printf("fd %d\n",fd);
        exit(0);

    }

    int length=1024000;
    int x=0;
    char buffer[length-1];
    while(x<length)
    {
        int valread=read(fd,&buffer[x],length);
        if(valread==0)
        {
            printf("zero bytes read\n");
            
            break;
        }
        
        if(valread<0)
        {
            printf("read return negative %d %d\n",valread,errno);

            break;
        }
        x=x+valread;
        
    }
    if(x>0)
    {
        printf("%x",buffer);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("ops no read\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: do you have sufficient rights? **what is the error?**

Comment: @OznOg I am running program with sudo su root priviledged

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```c
char buffer[length-1];
int valread=read(fd,&buffer[x],length);
```

That is a very bad idea. You allocate enough space for `length - 1` bytes then attempt to read `length` bytes into that space.

If the read gets the largest possible size, you will have a buffer overflow, well into undefined behaviour territory<sup>(1)</sup>.

And, on top of that, you attempt to read `length` bytes even though you may have already read some in earlier iterations of the loop. You should be:

- Using the correct length for the buffer; and
- Adjusting the length down based on what you've already read.

And, though this may not be a problem, one meg is quite a lot of data to put on the stack (which is often limited in size by default). If that *is* the case, you may be better of using `malloc` to get a dynamic buffer, such as:

```c
char *buffer = malloc(length);
// make sure buffer != NULL, then use it.
free(buffer);
```

---

So, something like (untested but you should hopefully get the idea):

```c
int x = 0, length = 1024000; // with malloc if needed.
char buffer[length];
while (x < length) {
    int valread = read(fd, &buffer[x], length - x);
    if (valread == 0) {
        printf("zero bytes read\n");
        break;
    }
    else if (valread < 0) {
        printf("read return negative %d %d\n",valread,errno);
        break;
    }

    x += valread;
}
```

---

<sup>(1)</sup> An *example* of what may happen is that overflowing the buffer will affect other variables on the stack in certain ways.

For example, it may corrupt `x` which would mean your next read could go to some arbitrary place in memory possibly corrupting other things as a result.

Or it could corrupt `fd` which would make the next read likely to fail with an invalid file descriptor.You can check the actual behaviour by simply printing out those two values before any use. Given the fact you mention "bad file descriptor error", that's possibly the most likely scenario here.

But, to be honest, the best solution is probably just to avoid undefined behaviour (though it may still be educational for you to find out the effects).

Comment: While this is correct, it does unfortunately not answer the question, why the OP cannot open the character device.

Comment: @thebusybee: OP stated "why bad file descriptor error at time of ***read***", not open. Hence UB probably plays a part given the buffer oveflow.

Comment: Well, it's the last sentence: "_I am not getting this line passed `int fd=open(`[...]_"

Comment: @busybee sorry may be a typo but my open call is successfully called. I edited the question

Comment: If I reduce value of  length then no issue why is that

Comment: @user786, it really doesn't matter. UB is UB and *anything* can happen. The sensible thing is to avoid it rather than try to work around it :-)

Comment: Thanks for ur edit. So u are saying if I use malloc then bad file descriptor at the time of read will not cause. And this make sense. If I read less than 1mb then no issue. Thanks are u confirming it

Comment: @user786: no, I'm saying make sure you shouldn't write beyond the end of your buffer. The two bullet points should be enough to guarantee that. The use of `malloc` is only if you encounter problems by trying to store too much on the stack. This is possibly not the case since you generally (not guaranteed) get a core dump at the start of the function rather than after opening the file.